# permanently Illuminate a 2D map as you walk by

Tags: unity-game-engine

As my player walks across a dungeon, surrounding floor and walls tiles are being illuminated by a point light centered on the player itself, and that works just fine. What I need now is to somehow change permanently already visited areas by making them somewhat more visible. My first idea was to change material of visited tiles but that would render a segmented "squared" illuminated effect, as tiles are 35x35 px while what I am trying to do is to make permanently visible a uniform area, that is the area that has been illuminated by the (circular) point light, and not a set of squared tiles. How can be that be achieved ?

Updated request.
As I could not find a suitable answer I switched to solution "B"...
Visited tiles get somewhat illuminated in their center. That accounts for making visited tile "marked" as such. What I can't get now is preventing the light from filtering through Walls, Doors, ecc...
As light cannot pass through a wall in reality, so it should not in the game. The point light carried by the player correctly illuminates tiles within a certain range but does not get blocked by opaque materials, thus revealing close, never visited rooms' content.
Unfortunately up to now I could not find a solution to this in a top-down 2d Unity environment.

[image: Visited Tiles]
[image: Light passing through doors and walls]

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use an alpha mask to store illumination.

On every move of your player, you would increase the alpha value on this area on your mask, making the area less transparent and thereby brighter. Furthermore, you could darken the previously visited area a bit.

The simplest approach I can think of is to store this mask as a regular 8-bit bitmap.
Here is some illustration of my idea. I hope this will help with your problem even though it is not a unity specific solution.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Florian I've been suggested a similar workaround on Unity forum, yet I cant figure out how to to access an AREA on the alpha mask. If the mask is a single object (kind of a "giant tile"), how can I modify a part of it ?
I If I knew how to access and modify PARTS of an object could simply change part of floor tiles, but I can't. Squared tiles can be only accessed as a whole.. so please help me understand what you mean by programmatically updating a single 8 bit bitmap in Unity every frame.

Comment: Hi Luke, it seems that you would have to use Texture2D and call SetPixel() to change values on a texture. Additionally, for applying the alpha to your tiles you need a shader. .https://forum.unity.com/threads/dynamic-alpha-channel-on-texture-to-create-dynamic-transparancy.311339/

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right direction Florian. Actually there exist mask and sprite mask element in newest Unity versions, but I cannot figure out how to programmatically change (expand) the shape of the mask over the random path the character decides to walk the map. I'm not even sure this is feasible. That looks quite overkill for what I'm trying to do, using a framework that should facilitate tasks like this.

Comment: Yeah, that's an argument. Can you upload some pictures of your game, not that this would be really beneficial for solving your problem, but I'm quite interested in how it looks like. Maybe you can search for tutorials, where such a feature is implemented?